# Convert elapsed time to numeric in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

i got a question :
How can i convert an elapsed time like 835:0:44 
to numeric for summing and average ?
 i tried things like instr and then tonumber and then avergae the outcome.
but i miss the minutes and seconds then.

Comment: When working with mixed units like this you need to convert everything to the smallest unit. So convert the hours and minutes to seconds and add everything together to get the total elapsed time in seconds. Then to display them again, break them back out into _hours:minutes:seconds_ again.

Comment: This is what i have been trying now.
Only my time format is variable, then its xxx:xx:xx and other time its xx:x:x 


local numbervar hours;  
local numbervar minutes;  
local numbervar seconds;  
hours := tonumber({TASKS.ELAPSETIME}[1 to 2])* 3600;  
minutes := tonumber({TASKS.ELAPSETIME}[4 to 5]) * 60;  
seconds := tonumber({TASKS.ELAPSETIME}[7 to 8]);  
hours + minutes + seconds;